# Nginx configuration for React application

Tags: reactjs, nginx, webpack

I'm trying to get an nginx server for my react application. I have the following directory structure.

```
/node_modules
  - react
  - react-dom
  ...
/dist
  - index.html
  - bundle.js
  - styles.css
```

My current nginx configuration file looks like this:

```
server {
  listen 80;

  server_name localhost;

  location /node_modules {
    root /var/www/app;
  }

  location / {
    root /var/www/app/dist;
    autoindex on;

    try_files $uri /index.html =404;
  }
}
```

The actual problem that I'm having is that `try_files` is not behaving as I think it should. Every file is being load correctly except for bundle.js and styles.css. When this two files are requested nginx is serving index.html instead of them. Based on my configuration, try_files is not finding bundle.js in `/var/www/app/dist/bundle.js` (I verified the file is in the correct place) and then using index.html as the fallback.

Any ideas on why this could be happening ?

Comment: Why would you want to expose the `node_modules` directory?

Comment: Because some dependencies contains assets like js or css. My actual problem was not related to nginx directives but a ENV var replacing logic that was wrong.